# MPI - Trying print broadcast variable after the barrier, showing some other variable

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I started with MPI learning. I have used a MPI_Barrier after MPI_Broadcast, in which i am broadcasting a variable to all the processes. But when I print the broad casted variable it is some value coming from memory but not from the broadcast. Not sure where I am doing wrong. Any suggestions please.

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int x, comm_sz, my_rank;

  MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

  if(my_rank == 0){     
    x = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    MPI_Bcast(&x, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(my_rank != 0){
    printf("x is %d\n", x);
}

  MPI_Finalize();   
}
```

I just want to do some operations after the value is broad casted to all the processes.

Comment: Just move your `MPI_Bcast()` out of your `if` statment and all should work better, even without barrier.

Comment: Thanks Gilles it is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies in this area.

```
if(myRank == 0){      
    x = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    MPI_Bcast(&x, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(my_rank != 0){
    printf("x is %d\n", x);
}
```

**MPI_Bcast** should be run by all processes like so because otherwise the values of x will never be populated on the non-root (rank == 0) processes.

```
if(myRank == 0){      
    x = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
}

MPI_Bcast(&x, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(my_rank != 0){
    printf("x is %d\n", x);
}
```

Since **MPI_Bcast** is blocking, the call to **MPI_Barrier** becomes unnecessary because a given process will not proceed until said process has received the broadcasted value of **x**.

[See for more details](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Bcast.3.php)

Comment: Just a remark: although `MPI_Bcast()` is blocking, it doesn't synchronise the MPI processes. What this blocking means is that after the call returns, it is safe to use the communication buffer, as it is not needed any more, neither for sending, nor for receiving. But that doesn't mean that any of the other processes of the communication have started or finished the call... The only existing temporal synchronisation MPI call is `MPI_Barrier()`. That said, the barrier is definitely not needed here and can safely be removed.